# App getting crashed while using ViewController continuously for 4 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

```
ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *NewPrciousCltnVw;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *NewFashionCltnVw;
+ (NSString *)stringVariable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
+ (NSString *)proVariable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *imageSlider;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblNewArrivals;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblFeaturedProducts;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *roundedoffers;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lbloffers;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *offersSlider;

@end
```

This is my Storyboard

[image]

Here ViewController is the 'front-view' of SWRevealViewController and Menu ViewControler is the 'rear-view'.If I continuously use push to SecondViewController and back to ViewController for more than 3 minutes my app gets crashed. Somebody help me out from this issue and thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your crash report

Comment: also upload your code.

Comment: It shows like Lost Connection but my device has been plugged only

Comment: maybe you have you a retain cycle happening?

Comment: I suggest using Instruments to see if memory is increasing as you use your app.  If it is, Instruments can tell you which objects are responsible.

Comment: I have checked there are no memory leakages..and app crashes only when I run app in device not in simulator